# Cancelling creation of a new thread using AsycTask in android

Tags: android

I have a class ShapesActivity.java and have a button in its layout. I have another file ShapesView.java that extends view. I have AsyncTask in this class to move a circle created. Now when I click on th e stop button in ShapesActicity.java class, I want no new creation of thread and hence the circle should stop where ever it is.
I am unable to implement the event handler of button click in ShapesView and hence cannot call cancel(true) to stop new thread from being created.
Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simply animate a circle?  If so, you may be overcomplicating things.  You don't really need an AsyncTask to accomplish something like that.  Just override your custom view's draw() method and paint to the provided Canvas object.

Comment: It was a requirement to use it. Any ways could you tell how to stop it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your AsyncThread responsible for creating the view, or animating the view?  You say that pressing STOP should prevent further CREATION, which doesn't have anything to do with animation.

If you meant to say that your thread is animating the view, and STOP should stop the animation, then you can simply add a method to your AsyncTask implementation which sets flag which tells the animation loop to stop animating.  Then your STOP button just needs to call `mAnimThread.stopAnimating()`.  Something like:

```
class MyAnimThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    boolean mRunning = true;

    public void stopAnimating()
    {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        while(mRunning)
        {
            //animate
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Adding some of your own source code would help in understanding the problem.

Comment: The Stop button is not a part of the view so it cannot call in this way. It is part of another java class that has a layout of button on top and the view at the bottom. Hope I am making sense to you.

Comment: So how do I refer from One class to the other?

Comment: Ok, in the `onCreate()` of your activity, you need to get a reference to the view.  Something like `View shapeView = findViewById(R.id.shape_view);` where `shape_view` is the `id=` attribute in the xml layout file for the activity.  Then you can call methods in your custom view, like `shapeView.cancelAnimation();`, from your STOP button handler.